# Does anyone have a CUSP plugin for Eclipse (Common Lisp)

Tags: eclipse, plugins, common-lisp, cusp

Does anyone have a CUSP plugin for Eclipse. Unfortunately  http://www.sergeykolos.com/cusp/update is not working.

Comment: https://code.google.com/p/cusp/

Comment: And how can i download it??

Comment: it's a subversion repository. see the source tab.

Comment: For newer googlers: Dandelion seems better maintained: https://github.com/Ragnaroek/dandelion and we can find a cusp mirror on github: https://github.com/budden/cusp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you can run it from source in the [wiki page](https://code.google.com/p/cusp/wiki/DevStart) there is an easy explanation :

> ## Getting Cusp running from source
>
> - Check out the repository with the command "svn checkout http://cusp.googlecode.com/svn/ cusp-read-only"
> - Import the project into Eclipse (File > Import > Existing Projects into Workspace)
> - Create an sbcl directory in the project. Put sbcl in there. Make sure to include the sbcl executable.
> - Run Cusp as a plugin, and behold the glory! (Run > Run... > Eclipse Application > New)
> - Sometimes you need to provide .classpath file to compile and launch plugin from development environment. Here is what you can do: Go to File->New->Project->Plug-in Project Keep everything default and create temporary project. Then go to project folder and find .classpath file. Copy it to jasko.tim.lisp folder before importing plugin to Eclipse using File->Import->Existing Projects into Workspace.
> - On Windows it may be necessary to edit jasko.tim.lisp\build.properties and remove trailing slashes from all directory names. Also Eclipse Plug-in libraries need to be added as an external dependency (project properties->Java Build Path->Libraries->Add Library->Plug-in Dependencies)

from the original repo

https://code.google.com/p/cusp/

I also thing that now is pretty easy to make emacs a productive Common Lisp IDE with Slime

after installing quicklisp on SBCL https://www.quicklisp.org/beta/

> To install and configure SLIME, use:
>
> ```
> (ql:quickload "quicklisp-slime-helper")
> ```

Then follow the directions it displays. quicklisp-slime-helper will create a file you can load in Emacs that configures the right load-path for loading Quicklisp's installation of SLIME.

Here is a video for windows

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VnWVu8VVDbI